# How to solve the ODE with variable coefficients?

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve the ODE: $L(\varphi)=\ddot \varphi - (n-2) \tanh t \dot \varphi + n\varphi\frac{1}{\cosh^2 t }=0$, where  $\sinh t=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$, $\cosh t=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$, $\tanh t=\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}$. The answer is $L(\varphi)=0$ has two linearly independent solutions $\varphi_1(t) = \tanh t$ and $\varphi_2(t)  = e^{(n-2)|t|}(1 + O(e^{t}))$ as $t \rightarrow -\infty$. (for e.g., $\varphi_2(t) = \tanh t \int_{c}^t \frac{\cosh^n \tau}{\sinh^2 \tau} d\tau$ for some $c < 0$.) But, how can I find the two linearly independent solutions?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You have already given explicit formulas for $\varphi_1(t)$ and $\varphi_2(t)$, which are solutions and are independent. Sounds like you already have an answer.

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault! The solutions are given from some papers, I don't list it here. My question is how to find the two soutions like $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$ in details. This is shown in that paper, but not given the detials.

Comment: This looks very much like the Legendre differential equation. Try to make $t=\tanh(x)$

Comment: Could you list the paper you are referring to, please?

Comment: It was stated in the paer：The axisymmetric $\sigma_k$-Nirenberg problem, in the page 57.